# How to add multiple data files (.csv) to Power BI?

Tags: csv, powerbi, data-visualization

Every time I try to add multiple files together they get combined. Imagine having 20 CSV files, it would be so tedious to add the files one-by-one in Power Bi. I was wondering if there was any way to add multiple CSV files together without merging them?

The reason I want them to be separate is so that the data is segregated and I can access them easily.

Comment: What do you mean by Added together? Are all your csv's having the same columns?

Comment: Why don't you use `Folder` data source? See [Combine files (binaries) in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-combine-binaries).

Comment: The folder combines all the data into one file. I want to separate all the data files so I can access them separately.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing all csv files in a single folder and then given location of that folder to powerbi while importing.

For reference: https://exceleratorbi.com.au/combine-csv-files-power-query/

Comment: I have tried this and it works like a charm. But I am not looking for this. I do not want to combine all my CSV files into one. I want to import all of them in power BI separately.